origin point touching with object in mirror modifier
I'm trying to make a sword, but when I use the Mirror modifier, the mesh overlaps with the origin point, creating a strange artifact. I tried changing the origin, but it’s not working



hello could you please share your file?

https://we.tl/t-axCXkIspKC @moonboots

it's because of the Bevel modifier, not sure why it does that, maybe first apply the Scale and choose Geometry > Miter Outer > Sharp?

its because of bad topology, thanks @moonboots
